# Adjoint functor theorem on certain categories

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

I am reading Lurie's notes on Bousfield localization, attached below. I have the following questions:

1. I don't get why the inclusion $C \subset Sp$ preserves homotopy colimits from assumption (*)
2. Can I have the precisely statement and reference to the version of the adjoint functor theorem?
3. Does everything work if I replace $Sp$ by $D(A),D^+(A), D^-(A)$ where $A$ is an abelian category?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not from assumption (*), but from the assumption about that that $C$ is closed under homotopy colimits.
2. I guess he's talking about Brown representability. Just Google that, noting that the homotopy categories of $C$ and of spectra are triangulated.
3. Yes, although chain complexes is a better analog of spectra than the derived category is.